# How can I install a kernel to my Jupyter Notebook to run Python 2.7 (having installed Python 3.6 via Anaconda3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I run Windows 10 and have installed Python 3.6 via Anaconda3.  I would like to run Python 2.7 as well for the well known reasons.

I presume that one way to do so would be to install a separate kernel in my Jupyter Notebook that would run Python 2.7 (another way would be to be able to switch within the same Jupyter Notebook instance between Python 3.6 and Python 2.7 -- which I do not know if it is feasible and if yes what I should do).

I have installed Python 2.7 in my PC in a separate directory (C:\Python27).

How can I achieve my objectives?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this. I followed this.

```
https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097
```